# how to link db2 table column to another object?

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange, data-linking

I am new to `DB2` and I'm working with an `IBM i series` system. I have an object with a special column "`X`". I want to store data for `X` in another object whenever some criteria satisfied and I can get data from the original object for both special records(which data have been stored in another object) and normal data (which values stored in the original object).

How can I link this column to another object? can `DB2 data link`: [data-link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/sqlp/rbafydatalinks.htm) help me in this situation? if yes, how can I implement that? I can't find a complete tutorial on how to do this.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you read the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafydatalinks.htm) in the knowledge center?

Comment: There's what looks like a nice section on DataLinks in here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafypdf.pdf (IBM i Database SQL Programming). Explains how to set the thing up end to end. Thanks for asking, I didn't personally even know you could do this on IBM i (though I suppose I should have guessed given it's part of DB2 on LUW). Cue some playing next time I get my hands on an IBM i partition.

Comment: @MandyShaw Thanks for your response. That helped me :)